# Treat Hard Drive as Optical Drive

Tags: hard-drive, optical-drive

I've recently bought a new laptop (running Windows 10), but unlike my old laptop this one doesn't feature an internal optical drive. I have bought an external optical drive, but it is unreliable and not very portable.

I have a game on disk and I would like to be able to run it from an external hard drive or USB instead of having to take the disk drive with me when I travel. The game requires two parts to run - the first is a downloadable part which I have installed on my laptop. The second is in the disk. Once the game has started it does not require the disk - I'm pretty sure the game only requires it upon startup to make sure that you own the disk and have not illegally downloaded the game.

I have tried copying all of the disk files onto an external hard drive and running the installed software, but it doesn't recognize it and informs me that the game disk has not been inserted.

Is there a way that I can trick the software into seeing the external hard drive as a disk drive? Or is there another way I can run the game without the disk?

Thanks.

Comment: Windows 8+ support mounting .ISO;  There is multiple ( dozens ) of virtual disk applications on the market.  If your not using Windows 8 or above use one of those.  Neither of these will get around DRM.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 has a handy feature there you can open and mount an iso file directly with windows explorer. Assuming the game doesn't have onerous copy protection, you might be able to image the cd into an ISO (I typically use [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) installed via [ninite](https://ninite.com/) to avoid the adware in the installer, but only cause I've not found an alternative I like).

So, create an image of the disk (NOT copy its contents over to your hard drive), rightclick on the image file, open in explorer, and it may work.

Comment: Windows 7 comes with ISOBURN.EXE so I would suspect WIn10 may as well.  InfraRecorder is another alternative to ImgBurn.

Comment: Does it do disk to iso? This is the first I've heard of it. Yes, windows 10 has it.

Comment: Sorry, forget ISOBURN.  That goes the other way; I must not have been sufficiently thinking when I made that comment.  To use ISOs, [MS KB 916902](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916902) - [Microsoft Virtual CD-ROM Control Panel package](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/b/6/7b6abd84-7841-4978-96f5-bd58df02efa2/winxpvirtualcdcontrolpanel_21.exe) - [Review](http://www.softwarepatch.com/windows/xpvirtualcd.html) - or [ImDisk](http://ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) may be solutions.  I've used D-Tools (Daemon Tools ver 3.47). But some of this info was for older operating systems.